# STS 2.8.0 StartExplorer/Legacy Plugin install issues

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I love [StartExplorer](http://startexplorer.sourceforge.net/update/) but after installing the latest STS 2.8.0 I see this when I try to install StartExplorer and other plugins

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1319291110423 (SharedProfile_com.springsource.sts.ide 1.0.0.1319291110423)
  Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1319291110423 (SharedProfile_com.springsource.sts.ide 1.0.0.1319291110423) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.100.20110804-1717]' but it could not be found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah

I found this as I was writing the question, so figured might as well finish and share:

https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2261

If you are seeing this it's because STS is installed in a read-only dir and you need with admin rights or to install it elsewhere

Comment: I want to add that, at least on some linux systems, if you change the owner on the directory to be writeable by your user, STS will apparently think it's a new installation and prompt you for a new workspace location. Your old workspace will still load fine, though. (This bit me personally.)